# How do I make glass/blur background like in windows 11 menus and apps in a html element with css?

Tags: css

Is there any way to make glassy/blur background element or a card in html with css which is like the start menu bg in windows 11?
[image]

edit: I mean I am able to do it till the backdrop filter part but don't know how to get that noise effect, I tried putting a noise png as a background but it doesn't looks like the one I am trying to achieve

[image]

the noise seems too much.

Comment: There are certainly ways to do this, when you tried to do so where did you get stuck? Can you share your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code? Can you explain how existing answers on the site failed to answer your specific use-case?

Comment: I edited my question with what I achieved so far, please look into it if you can, thanks for your help.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Can you link me to one? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example, play with it for better or more suitable results. Thanks for Unsplash for the testing image. Next time, try to make your question more clear and show your work!

```css
body {
    /* Image for testing purposes, thanks for Unsplash */
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519681393784-d120267933ba?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1124&q=100");
    background-position: center;
}
.glass {
    /* CSS for Glass UI, play with it for better or more suitable results */
    backdrop-filter: blur(25px) saturate(180%);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(25px) saturate(180%);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.57);
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(209, 213, 219, 0.3);
    /* <div> size */
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    /* Make nice text */
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="glass">Hello!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I am more of stuck at the noise part, I am sorry for not mentioning in the question, thanks nonetheless.

Comment: @lifeisstrange have you tried to just apply that translucent noise png as the element's background image?

Comment: yes I did, but the noise looks too sharp/ too much, it is much smoother in windows 11 menu.

Comment: @lifeisstrange try with another noise image, a bit more translucent for example.

Comment: @lifeisstrange It's also better to show your code so far. What do you mean by the "noise" part? Do you want to edit the "blur", "saturation" or "opacity" value?